# Passing an lvalue to rvalue template parameter won't allow me to declare const T& var

Tags: c++

Just a quick query regarding reference collapsing, and this is my code:

```
template<typename B>
void funct(B&& b)
{
    const B woi= 10; // ERROR: B is int& , how come it won't let me make const int& var?                     // If B is int(just incase i am wrong), it still won't work
    b = 11;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    int k =10;  
    funct(k);
    std::cout<<k<<std::endl; //prints 11;

    return 0;
}
```

I was playing around and doing some testings. How come it won't let me create `const int& var` wherein B is type `int&`?

I did another attempt to make sure that it's `int&` and here's the code:

```
template<typename B>    //B will be deducated as B& or int&
void funct2(B&& b){     //receives lvalue refence, param will be B& b

const B p = 5;          //ERROR eventhough B is B& or int&
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {



    //make ref
    int l = 5;
    int & m = l;
    funct2(m);  //passed an lvalue reference


    return 0;
}
```

Question: how come it won't let me reuse `int&` as `const` ?

Edit: I am aware that `const int&` is mainly used for lvalues but `const int & var = 10` totally works fine on main/functions but not with `B`.

Example:

```
template<typename B>
void funct(B&& b)
{

const int& p = 10;
//const B woi= 10;  gives me errors

}
```

Though they are supposed to be the same.

Comment: The correct way to do this is `const decltype(+declval<B>())& woi`

Comment: Can you elaborate why do i have to go such lengths in order for me to do a simple `&` reference??

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb is that preferable to a simple `std::remove_reference_t`?

Comment: @TartanLlama yes because it is shorter.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb i get an error if i compile using that code.  `declval was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @CarloBrew it's `std::declval`. You'll also need to `#include <utility>`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb but it's not shorter, and also less clear. Is there a semantic difference?

Comment: @TartanLlama `echo -n 'std::remove_reference_t<B>' | wc -c` vs `echo -n 'decltype(+declval<B>())' | wc -c` gives 26 vs 23. Not sure why you say mine isn't shorter. There is a semantic difference with types that overload `operator+` and with `volatile int&`. Mine gives `const int&` yours would give `const volatile int&` I think. Not sure whether that matters.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb that's assuming you've declared `using std::declval;`. Declaring `using std::remove_reference_t;` makes my version shorter. I'd think using the `decltype` expression for types that overload `operator+` would give pretty surprising results.  Maybe the most correct solution would be removing the reference and volatile? Or just using `std::decay`.

Comment: @tartan you win :) i am joking anyway heh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that adding `const` to `int&` means a const reference, not a reference to const, i.e. `const B` where `B` is `int&` is *not* `const int&`. A const reference is just the same as a normal reference, so it can't bind to rvalues.

If you want a `const int&` both when an lvalue or rvalue is passed in, you can do this:

```
const std::remove_reference_t<B>& woi; //c++14
const typename std::remove_reference<B>::type& woi; //c++11
```

Comment: Oh geez, totally forgot about that part but i am also curious about how `const & int var= 2` works in main but not on a function.

Comment: `const & int var = 2` is not valid C++.

Comment: It compiles with mine though?

Comment: In your question you changed it to say `const int &`, that's completely different from `const & int`.